# Reading from Standard Output in C is possible?

Tags: c, redirect, output, standards

I want to read from standard output ,like a file or file stream, without creating an auxiliary file ,i try using fgets(buffer,MAXLINE,stdout); 
but it doesn't work.
It's possible or i have to create an auxiliary file??

Comment: What is wrong with reading from stdin?

Comment: Standard Output used to be a printer. Not readable.

Comment: Cause I'm working on an UDP application, one of the operation possible for the client is asking the list the file in the server folder, the server has to execute the system call :< ls > that print the result on stdout .

Answer (score 1):

> Reading from Standard Output in C is possible?

No.